# SQL Server XML Value formatting newline

Tags: sql-server, xml, formatting

T-SQL XML value loses new line formats

I have XML file loaded into SQL server. I query this file to extract the nodes with value.

The problem is the new line characters are lost while selection. How to retain formatting so that when I display the text on the web, it not appear messy without line breaks.

See text and screenshots for details

[image]

[image: Editor shows that new lines \n are lost]

T-SQL code:

```
declare @Text xml ;
set @Text= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<topic>
  <L1>
    <Subject>Subject text</Subject>
    <Details>
      Story Details are

      This is paragraph

      Text after After two line breaks

      Text after After two line breaks

    </Details>
  </L1>
</topic>'

;with t as (select @Text [xmlcolumn])
--select * from t
SELECT  x.a.value('(Subject)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Subject]
,       x.a.value('(Details)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Details]
FROM   t
cross apply
t.xmlcolumn.nodes('//L1') x(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I misread your question - the problem with the newlines is purely in SQL Server Management Studio - it cannot represent those newlines. When you read your XML from an application in C# or VB.NET, those newlines will still be there - trust me.

But this original answer might also be relevant in other cases - you need to be aware that SQL Server is not storing your XML "as is" - it parses and converts it. So when you ask to get it back, it might look slightly different, but it's still the same XML functionally.

---

Yes, this is normal, expected behavior.

SQL Server stores your XML in a **tokenized** format - e.g. it doesn't store the actual, textual representation of your XML, but it parses and tokenizes your XML into XML fragments that are then stores inside this `XML` datatype.

Therefore, when you query it again, you'll get back a **semantically** correct and identical representation - but there's a possibility that certain textual representations are different.

E.g. when you pass in an empty XML element something like this:

```
<MyEmptyElement></MyEmptyElement>
```

you'll get back the "short" form of that when you retrieve the XML from SQL Server again:

```
<MyEmptyElement />
```

This is not the exact same text - but it's 100% the same XML from a semantic perspective.

As far as I know, you cannot influence this behavior in any way - you'll just have to live with it.